# MySQL COUNT of Grouped rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have following table 'tbl_pads' with one column named 'id_pad' with 6 rows:

```
pad_1 |
pad_1 |
pad_2 |
pad_3 |
pad_3 |
pad_3 |
```

With `SELECT id_pad FROM tbl_pads GROUP BY id_pad`
I get following rows:

```
pad_1 |
pad_2 |
pad_3 |
```

With `SELECT COUNT(id_pad) AS COUNT_PADS FROM tbl_pads GROUP BY id_pad` I get following rows

```
2 | 
1 | 
3 |
```

How can get the rows Count of the Grouped Statement? I expect the result 3

Comment: @DanielW. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @LikiCrus That was posted as an answer a while ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rows count of group statement in single row then you can use below query.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_pad) over() AS COUNT_PADS FROM tbl_pads group by id_pad limit 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_pad) FROM tbl_pads;
```

And if you want multiple row based on group statement and rows count along with this then you can go with this.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_pad) over(), id_pad AS COUNT_PADS FROM tbl_pads group by id_pad;
```

See the db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97021f2b9a1cb360c1258a2bfb4e072a

Answer (score 4):

Another was of phrasing the question is that you want to get the number of different `id_pad` values. Once you phrase it like that, it becomes clearer that using a distinct count will work:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_pad) FROM tbl_pads
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of individual id_pads.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl_pads
>     (`id_pad` varchar(5))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tbl_pads
>     (`id_pad`)
> VALUES
> ('pad_1'),
>     ('pad_1'),
>     ('pad_2'),
>     ('pad_3'),
>     ('pad_3'),
>     ('pad_3')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(id_pad) AS COUNT_PADS FROM tbl_pads WHERE id_pad = 'pad_3'
> ```

> ```
> | COUNT_PADS |
> | ---------: |
> |          3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4dc6e262626d636eaeb575b561eae158)*

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Barmar you are absolutely right